# pip install not installing part of the repository

Tags: python, django, pip

I encounter the problem trying to install [django-bleach](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-bleach) (and similarly: [django-html_sanitizer 0.1.2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-html_sanitizer/) has the same problem). 
I tried several ways to install it from my requirement.txt :
`django-bleach`
`django-bleach==0.1.2` (this is the lates version at the time I write it)
`git+https://bitbucket.org/ionata/django-bleach.git@5bdae1b0bd86#egg=django_bleach`

All these methods don't work : the directory `/templatetags` is not installed in my virtual environment ( `site-packages/django_bleach` ).

Any idea how to do? (I don't want to copy the files from the repository, it won't deploy easily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just found a solution :
`setup.py` isn't configured to take into account the folder /templatetags.

Just add, in the `setup.py`, to the line `packages=['django_bleach']` : `'django_bleach.templatetags'` , so it looks like this (thx to frog32 !):

```
    ...
    packages=[
        'django_bleach',
        'django_bleach.templatetags'
    ],
    ...
```

If the package is not yours (like in my case), you need to fork it (usually on Bitbucket or GitHub), change the `setup.py` in your repository. In the case you use Pip, you should configure your `requirement.txt` to get the package from YOUR repository, here my example is :

```
    (other packages)
    ...
    django-bleach
    ...
```

becomes:

```
    ...
    git+https://sebastien_worms@bitbucket.org/sebastien_worms/django-bleach.git
    ...
```

In my case I just have to run `pip install -r requirement.txt` and I'm done !

Answer (score 1):

you should add the package django_bleach.templatetags to packages

```
packages=[
    'django_bleach',
    'django_bleach.templatetags',
]
```

package_data is intended for non python files

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this ! I hope you don't mind, I'm updating my answer to avoid letting errors in it (and +1 to your answer ;) )